# Mysql num rows issue

Tags: php, mysql

I run this query to check if cat_name already exists it the mysql database... but it's show a warning messag.

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs......"

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['cat_name']))
{
$cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['cat_name'])));   
$err = array();

$ch = mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM categories WHERE cat_name = '$cat_name' ");
$num = mysql_num_rows($ch);

if(empty($cat_name))
$err[] = "Category field empty";
    elseif(is_numeric($cat_name))
    $err[] = "Category name should be string, ex: category name";
        elseif($num > 0)
        $err[] = "Category name already exits, please choose another name";
            else
            {
                if(strlen($cat_name) < 3)
                $err[] = "Category name at least 3 or more    
characters";    
            }

if(!empty($err))
{
    foreach($err as $er)
    {
        echo "<font color=red>$er.</font>";
    }   
}
else
{
    $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categoires VALUES('',  
'$cat_name')"); 

    if($sql_insert)
    {
        echo "Successfully inserted your category name";    
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Something is wrong to add your cateogory name";
        mysql_error();  
    }

}


}
?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: The solution might be under the related tab on the right... ---->

Comment: $5 says you're wide open to SQL injection attacks.  Learn to use PDO with prepared queries.

Comment: @Brad see my full code is it now safe ? Because of i used mysql_real_escape_string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

For `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN` and other statements returning
resultset, `mysql_query()` returns a resource on success, or `FALSE` on
error.

`mysql_query()` will also fail and return `FALSE` if the user does not
have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

My best guess is that you have an error in your query.

Comment: Well @IsisCode, now please see my full code what is the error?

Comment: In your query, are your table names correct? Also, I can see a separate error in your script: $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categoires VALUES('',  
'$cat_name')");

Comment: Yes table names is correct. About INSERT statement, 1st values is Auto Increment values so that i used it empty.. is it right?

Comment: "INSERT INTO categories (cat_name) VALUES ('$cat_name')"

Comment: The auto increment value is automatic, no need to leave a blank string :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is failing (and returning `false`). Check `mysql_error` or the mysql/php error logs.